# How does the single responsibility principle relate to cats and dogs?

Tags: oop, design-patterns

From Wikipedia:

> Martin defines a responsibility as a reason to change, and concludes
>   that a class or module should have one, and only one, reason to
>   change.

However, every time you see an object-oriented analogy, they refer to cats and dogs, and how they have attributes and methods like so:

```
class Dog extends Animal{
    public breed;
    public dogYears;

    public function bark();
    public function move();
    public function sleep();
    etc, etc...
}
```

I find a better way to implement bark, so I do that. I see that the dog doesn't move properly, so I fix that. Etc etc. There are more than one reason to change the class.

So, why is this analogy always used? What would be a better way to adhere to the SRP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't take it so literally.

In your example, Dog is responsible for performing real life "dog actions", such as barking, moving and sleeping. You can see this as *one* responsability. The SRP states that `Dog` should not be responsible for perming any non-dog actions, such as logging his movements.

This prevents you from having to change the `Dog` class if you decide to change the logging mechanism - because performing "dog actions" and logging are two completely different responsibilities.

Comment: True. Otherwise every single action should be extracted to it's own class. Want increment variable? Create VariableIncrementor instance :)

Comment: Thanks. How about if I wanted `Dog` to play with `Cat`? Would a method inside the `Dog` class and inside the `Cat` class be okay - or should there be a `class Interact` for this action, separated from either class?

Comment: @tgun926 It really depends on what you're trying to model, I would need a bigger picture before making an informed decision. But generally, I wouldn't want `Dog` to be coupled to `Cat`. If anything, i'd make it interact with an abstract `Animal`.

Comment: I don't really have a model - just trying to understand when I should have separate classes and when I shouldn't.

Comment: The first rule of classes is that they should be small. The second rule of classes is that they should be smaller than that. The same rule for functions. But as with functions, smaller is the primary rule when it comes to designing classes. With functions we measure size by counting physical lines. With classes we use a different measure. We count responsibilities.